# Transform row data into stacked column data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this data:

| Est No | Names and roles |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | KAIROUZ, TONY - Snr M'ment & Meat Auth Sig; LAUBSCH, ASHLEY - Oper M'ment & Meat Auth Sig |
| 7 | ALLEN, CHRIS - Oper M'ment & Meat Auth Sig; BADMAN, MICHAEL - Qa M'ment & Meat Auth Sig; BAKER, ALAN - Contact Only - Listed Establishment; BROOKS, STEWART - Oper M'ment & Rfp & Meat Auth Sig |
| 8 | FANG, JENNY - Operational Management; LI, DAJIAN - Senior Management |

I want to transform it into:

| Est No | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | TONY KAIROUZ |
| 4 | ASHLEY LAUBSCH |
| 7 | CHRIS ALLEN |
| 7 | MICHAEL BADMAN |
| 7 | ALAN BAKER |
| 7 | STEWART BROOKS |
| 8 | JENNY FANG |
| 8 | DAJIAN LI |

There are 1866 rows / unique Est No's.

Each 'Names and roles' cell can contain an arbitrary number of different people.

I have been able to separate the names out into individual cells like this:

| Est No | Name | Name | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | TONY KAIROUZ | ASHLEY LAUBSCH |  |
| 7 | CHRIS ALLEN | MICHAEL BADMAN | ALAN BAKER |

But don't know how to stack the names into a single column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*There are many ways to work on this, but in terms of **flexibility**, I would use `POWER QUERY` here which can **effortlessly** do the automation thus saving **time and effort**. `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`*.

**Method Using `Excel Formulas`**

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A6</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Data, A2:B4,
     _EstN, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _NamesR, TAKE(_Data,,-1),
     _MaxDelimiters, MAX(LEN(_NamesR)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(_NamesR,";",))+1),
     _NamesExtracted, TEXTBEFORE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(";"&_NamesR,";",SEQUENCE(,_MaxDelimiters)),";")," - "),
     _ColToRows, TOCOL(_NamesExtracted,2),
     HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(_NamesExtracted<>"",_EstN),2),TEXTAFTER(_ColToRows,", ")&" "&TEXTBEFORE(_ColToRows,", ")))
```

---

**Method using `POWER QUERY`**

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Names and roles", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Names and roles"),
    #"Extracted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {{"Names and roles", each Text.Trim(Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, "-")), type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Text Before Delimiter", "Names and roles", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Names and roles.1", "Names and roles.2"}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{"Names and roles.2", "Names and roles.1"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Names")
in
    #"Merged Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Also, if you don't want to go through the long process, and want to continue from where you have left, then this will quite simpler using both `Excel Formulas` as well as `POWER QUERY`

[image]

---

```
=LET(α, B2:D3, HSTACK(TOCOL(IFS(α<>"",A2:A3),2),TOCOL(α,1)))
```

---

With `POWER QUERY` it will certainly less than minute to accomplish. Watch below.

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

Starting where you finished - here is one of the ways to skin this cat with array formulas.

[image: Use of dynamic arrays]

What I did:

1. Counted the dimension of your `Name` area and repeated the `EstNo` this many times.

`=TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(1,COUNTA(B3:D3),1),A4:A5))`

2. Converted your `Name` area to a single column. Note a 0 switch as second argument, it tells TOCOL to substitute zeroes where values are missing.

`=TOCOL(B4:D5,0,0)`

3. (optional) If you want to combine the two in a single array, HSTACK() them.

`=HSTACK(E4#,G4#)`

All three formulas can be nested into one, but if I did that, I'd check the integrity of the combined range and immediately copy it somewhere as plain values.

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(
_id,J21:J23,
_rg,K21:K23,
_s1,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("#",,_rg),";","#"),
_s2,TOCOL(_id&"-"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTSPLIT(_s1,"-"),",","")),
_s3,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("#",,IFERROR(_s2,"")),"-","#")),
_s4,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",,SUBSTITUTE(DROP(_s3,,1)," ","-")),"-",","),
HSTACK(DROP(_s3,,-1),VSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(_s4,2,1))))
```

[image: Result]